# Filter on relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to filter upon a relationship. In my db I've got awards and awards categories. I want retrieve only the featured and not nominated awards.

This is my model:

```
class AwardsAwardsCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'awards_awards_categories'
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True, default=generate_unique_id)
    awards = relationship("Award")
    award_id = Column(Text, ForeignKey("awards.id", ondelete='cascade'))
    nomination = Column(Boolean)

    def __json__(self, request):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "nomination": self.nomination
        }


class Award(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'awards'
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True, default=generate_unique_id)
    type = Column(Text)
    featured = Column(Integer)
    awards = relationship("AwardsAwardsCategory", lazy='joined')

    def __json__(self, request):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "type": self.type,
            "number_of_awards": len(self.awards),
            "featured": self.featured,

        }
```

This is the call I make:

```
    query = self.session.query(Award)
    query = query.join(AwardsAwardsCategory.awards)
    query = query.filter(Award.featured != 0)
    query = query.filter(AwardsAwardsCategory.nomination != True)
    q_results = query.all()
```

This results in the following query:

```
SELECT awards.id AS awards_id, awards.type AS awards_type, awards.featured AS awards_featured, awards_awards_categories_1.id AS awards_awards_categories_1_id, awards_awards_categories_1.award_id AS awards_awards_categories_1_award_id, awards_awards_categories_1.nomination AS awards_awards_categories_1_nomination 
FROM awards_awards_categories JOIN awards ON awards.id = awards_awards_categories.award_id LEFT OUTER JOIN awards_awards_categories AS awards_awards_categories_1 ON awards.id = awards_awards_categories_1.award_id 
WHERE awards.featured != 0 AND awards_awards_categories.nomination != true
```

It is almost correct except the WHERE clause is missing a condition:

```
 AND awards_awards_categories_1.nomination != true
```

How can I change my code so that it adds the last condition to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up filtering on the nomination on the application layer. It's nasty, but it works.

```
query = self.session.query(Award)
query = query.join(AwardsAwardsCategory.awards)
query = query.filter(Award.featured != 0)
query = query.filter(AwardsAwardsCategory.nomination != True)
q_results = query.all()

# remove all objects from the session in order to keep them in the db.
self.session.expunge_all()
for award_category in q_results:
    # keep a separate list of the awards, in order to keep the iteration going as desired
    awards = list(award_category)
    for award in award_category.awards:
        if award.nomination:
            awards.remove(award)
    def __json__(self, request):
        return {
             "id": self.id,
             "type": self.type,
             "number_of_awards": self.number_of_awards,
             "featured": self.featured,
        }
    award_category.number_of_awards = len(awards)
    award_category.__json__ = types.MethodType( __json__, a )
```

If anyone knows a how to do it better in SQLAlchemy please tell me!